# windows customscriptextension fails

Tags: terraform, azure-virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure, azure-vm

"commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -executionpolicy Unrestricted -File "./Add-WVDHostToHostpoolSpringORG4T.ps1" "

fails with the below error

Error: Code="VMExtensionProvisioningError" Message="VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'CustomScriptExtension'. Error message: "Command execution finished, but failed because it returned a non-zero exit code of: '1'. The command had an error output of: 'At \r\nC:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12\Downloads\0\Add-WVDHostToHostpoolSpringORG4T.ps1:1 \r\nchar:1\r\n+ <#\r\n+ ~~\r\nThe terminator '#>' is missing from the multiline comment.\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [],...' For more information, check the instance view by executing Get-AzVmssVm or Get-AzVm (https://aka.ms/GetAzVm). These commands can be executed using CloudShell (https://aka.ms/CloudShell)"\r\n\r\nMore information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/VMExtensionCSEWindowsTroubleshoot "
│

Comment: Hi @tandey, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Comment: Hi I figured out the problem was that in the reference script I didnt closed the comment

Answer (score 0):

•   I would suggest you to please try **executing the powershell script on a separate test VM first to ensure that the desired results are being achieved through the script**. Also, would suggest you to please refer the below community thread for the **appropriate usage of parameters to be used in custom script extension while deploying powershell script** through it.

***[Install applications or software on Azure VM with ARM Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71046833/install-applications-or-software-on-azure-vm-with-arm-template/71064540#71064540)***

Also, according to the error that you have encountered, it seems that you have ***missed adding a ‘#’ mark before as a prefix to the supposed comment remark in the script due to which the powershell script when executed is giving out an error*** stating the same. Or else that you might have ***added an extra ‘#’ mark before a supposed legit powershell command in the script due to which the script didn’t get executed*** and is giving out this error.

Kindly refer the below community thread also for more details into this: -

***[powershell is missing the terminator: "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706869/powershell-is-missing-the-terminator)***